# How to compute reflectance from an image given a wavelength (python)

Tags: image-processing, computer-vision, raspberry-pi3, imaging

I have recently come across a [paper](https://www.emerald.com/insight/content/doi/10.1108/SR-12-2016-0276/full/html) entitled, "Portable Multispectral Imaging System Based on Raspberry Pi".

In this work, the authors have presented a low-cost spectral imaging system using a raspberry pi.  This is done by light multiplexing through a LED panel where 8 selected wavelengths covering the spectrum UV to NIR is included.  The camera used is a Raspberry Pi NoIR, RGB camera add-on for raspberry pi that does not have any IR cut filter installed.

When the sample is situated in the corresponding position inside the prototype, the system takes a photograph at each available wavelength sequentially.

Here's an example of an image captured at different wavelengths:

[image: Photographs of a damaged apple]

[image: Images at 590 nm]

[image: and reflectance spectra of good and over-ripe peaches]

But I do not understand how they were able to compute the reflectance spectra in the plot.

Or did I understand it correctly that the reflectance spectra is the computed intensity, using the equation below?

[image: Intensity of an image]

Why would that be?  Can anyone please direct me to the proper readings or source materials in order to understand this concept?  Please enlighten me. I am new to this.  Thank you!

Comment: It seems you have to sign up to some academic journal or some Microsoft rubbish and get bugged for ever more to read that paper ‍♂️

Comment: You may access the paper here: https://sci-hub.se/10.1108/SR-12-2016-0276 @MarkSetchell

Comment: I don't know why academics don't share their code on Github like the rest of the world - anyone know? Maybe you could ask the author, this appears to be her homepage http://www.ugr.es/~nurilr/ Please share any updates you obtain on this interesting paper.